# How do I properly provide user field to ModelSerializer in Django Rest Framwork

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a django `Profile` model as:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    meta = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.created_by
```

And a serializer (which I know is not currently doing much)

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my update method in view, I can't ever seem to validate the serializers.

This is how I am going about it:

```py
profile = Profile()
profile.created_by = request.user
serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
```

`serializer.is_valid()` always returns `False`. And by the way, `request.user` is an authenticated `CustomUser`.

I have also tried setting

```py
serializer = ProfileSerializer(
                              instance=profile,
                              data={'created_by':request.user}
                              )
```

And many combinations thereof. What am I missing that the serializer can't be validated? Clearly there's some trouble with the user here.

Extra: I am new to DRF, why is the 'created_by' field set by default when DRF seems to know who the user is?

Comment: Did you tried to print `serializer.errors`?

Comment: Hey @AbdulNiyasPM yes. I get `{'created_by': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}` when I pass the `created_by` field as `request.user`, I get `{'created_by': [ErrorDetail(string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received CustomUser.', code='incorrect_type')]}`

Comment: I guess `data={'created_by':request.user.id}` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `created_by` field automatically, and make it read-only, so that users cannot edit the field, in your `ProfileSerializer`, you can use the [`CurrentUserDefault` class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) provided by DRF. Then you don't have to worry about explicitly updating your user in the view.

Here's how it would look like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
created_by = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

What the `CurrentUserDefault` does is basically [retrieve the authenticated user](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.3/rest_framework/fields.py#L281) from the request included in the serializer's context:

```
class CurrentUserDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.user = serializer_field.context['request'].user

    def __call__(self):
        return self.user
```